# How to find out what graphics driver is installed?

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, gpu

I installed Xubuntu 13.04 two months ago. But I don't know to find out which driver is installed for my GPU ( I mean graphic card driver ) or is it installed? I'm feeling something is wrong with my pc graphics.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Run `sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'` to see the video driver used, or `sudo lshw -c video` for more detail. [i915](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/gpu/i915.html), for example, means your video adapter uses the Intel 915 drivers; [nouveau](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) means you have the Open Source drivers for NVIDIA.

Comment: driver= nouveau latency=0
driver= i915 latency=0


what does it means?

Comment: empty besides latency=0

Answer (score 4):

In the Xubuntu menu click on *Settings Manager*. This will open the **Settings** window.

[image]

In the Settings window under the *Hardware* heading, click on the *Additional Drivers* icon. This will open the Software & Updates window and show the **Additional Drivers** tab.

[image]

If you have a graphics card driver installed, there will be a black dot appearing to the left of it, showing that it is installed. The recommended graphics card driver, if there is one in the list, is the one that has *[Recommended]* appearing after it. You can install the Recommended driver by selecting the Recommended driver from the list of drivers, clicking the **Apply Changes** button in the lower right corner of Additional Drivers, and then reboot to enable the graphics card driver.

You can also automatically install the same packages that recommended drivers option of Additional Drivers installs by using the `install` option of the ubuntu-drivers program from the terminal. The install command of ubuntu-drivers installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Ubuntu icon on the upper left corner.. then search for Additional Drivers.. click that.. wait for it to check.. and see if you have any driver checked on available.. if not .. you gotta "activate" meaning to install one of them.. it's better to stick with stable releases.. ( check the description of each ) Good luck

Comment: it told me there is no additional drivers available , it means my graphic card driver is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

You get a complete report by using `inxi -G` command:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Logitech BRIO Ultra HD Webcam type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid,uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 44.0 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati,modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,radeon,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 770 (ADL-S GT1)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2
```

You may need to install inxi first. I highly recommend it.

```
$ sudo apt install inxi
```