# Ubuntu 19.10 with Nvidia-340. GeForce 8600M GT Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia-geforce

Recently the nvidia-340.XXX driver stopped working. Both in Windows 10 and in Ubuntu 19.10. Has anyone got it to work? My only solution was to disable nouveau and load grub at a set resolution. This makes the system usable but not able to use second monitor. This is on a Qosmio Laptop G45. GeForce 8600M GT.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the overall approach to solving graphics driver problems is to boot into Recovery ... see https://askubuntu.com/a/1127240/18025 ... and remove all nvidia to only use nouveau then once you are OK with nouveau reinstall nvidia ... instead of downloading nvidia drivers yourself I suggest you pick them from Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers ... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/377205/how-to-find-out-what-graphics-driver-is-installed/377211  ... believe me graphics drivers today are MUCH better than they were years ago

Comment: I've done that several times. Still doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like a hardware problem since you mention its bad on linux and windows ... could not be a linux nvidia graphics driver issue if windows is bad too